# (Laravel) SSH install VS upload folder in server

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, localhost

Are there any differences between using ssh to install laravel

and

just upload my laravel project folder which works on localhost

Since I just upload my laravel project to server but appear Error500
So I want to follow the below tutorial to install a new laravel project with ssh and upload my project to replace it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsgWKuGk3yM

Comment: Have you checked the error logs for info?

Answer (score 0):

You must give write permissions to the storage and bootstrap/cache folder. If the problem still occurs, check error logs and post the error here.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your initial question which isn't very clear at all, wether there is a difference between uploading your project files and ssh-ing into your VPS or your VM: what is your working environment, and I assume you are uploading these files somewhere else?

There are 2 situations: you are just getting started, and in this case I recommend you follow the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/), not a YouTube video, and have a local instance where you can work and synchronise files easily between the guest and the host. I would recommend having a look over Homestead or Valet if you are on OS X or macOS. The documentation is very clear and concise.

The second one: you want to deploy your app, in this case a hosting management tool would help you out with this process (of course there is a much more to do with the configuration), as it's pretty much a chore to setup every requirement and dependency for your server, but that's an alternative too if you wish.

Comment: I am going to deploy my app. It can be run for my localhost through "php artisan serve". But when I iupload my project to server via FileZilla, it seems like no laravel thing appear.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? If you upload the files via FTP you cannot see the files reflected on the remote host? Again there are many management tools that help you deploy a Laravel app, I wouldn't advise you to deploy manually.